# Elasticsearch change similarities model of an index

Tags: elasticsearch

Can you change the similarities model of an index or do you need to rebuild the index?

This documents the similarities plugin, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

But the documentation does not mention if you are able to change the model on the fly.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment elasticsearch does not allow changing the similarity on the fly .
  https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4403

Comment: Would you recommend a specific similarity model to start testing with?