# BM25 Similarity Tuning in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The Elasticsearch [documentation says](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html) I can change the similarity for all fields by adding the following to `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
index.similarity.default.type: BM25
```

..which I've done, but I also want to fine tune the field-length normalisation, which it says I can do here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pluggable-similarites.html#bm25-tunability

But it doesn't tell me where/how to set the `k1` and `b` parameters. Is there a line I can add to `elasticsearch.yml` to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out this  [document](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/changing-similarities.html#changing-similarities) stating how you can configure BM25 similarity

Essentially you can define a custom bm25 similarity  similar to custom analyzers in the index setting

Example:

```
 curl -XPUT "http://<server>/<index>" -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "similarity": {
      "custom_bm25": { 
        "type": "BM25",
        "b":    0 ,
         "k1" : 0.9

      }
    }
  }'
```

Comment: Thanks! Will I need to rebuild the index after changing this or will a reboot suffice?

Comment: 1) changing the simlarity requires a index rebuild http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875703/elasticsearch-change-similarities-model-of-an-index 2) However as per http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/changing-similarities.html#changing-similarities once you have setup a custom similarity for index tweaking values of b,k1 just requires closing index, updating and reopen. However i have not tested the 2 point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my elasticsearch.yml file looks like.  This is with elasticsearch-2.3.2.

```
index :
  similarity:
    default:
      type: BM25
      b: 0.75
      k1: 1.2
```

Also, [here](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/) is a good reference for picking the tuning parameters.